# Number of ordered pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ which satisfy given equations

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1$$ and $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{1}{e}$$, where $(\alpha, \beta)=[-\pi, \pi]$. Then the number of ordered pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ which satisfy both the equations will be?

Correct answer is $4$.

I found value of $2\cos\alpha \cos\beta=\frac{e+1}{2e}$ and $2\sin\alpha \sin\beta=\frac{e-1}{2e}$ but don't seem to be heading anywhere near answer. How should I proceed?

Comment: 4 is the answer to which? $\alpha$ or $\beta$?

Comment: It means four ordered pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1=\cos0,\alpha-\beta=2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

Now as $(\alpha, \beta)\in[-\pi, \pi]$

either $\alpha=\beta$  or $\alpha=-\beta=\pm\pi$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks. I think I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Note that $-2 \pi \le \alpha-\beta \le 2 \pi$.

Therefore $\alpha-\beta=2\pi, $0$ ,-2\pi$.

However, for the equality to hold, $\alpha= \pi, \beta=-\pi$, or $\alpha=-\pi, \beta=\pi$, which are both impossible.

Therefore $\alpha= \beta$. However, $\cos (\alpha+\beta)=\cos (2\alpha)$ has $4$ solutions for $\frac{1}{e}$.